# Kinect: Extracting Color (rbg info) from certain Skeleton Joint Point. Getting Weird Results

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm hoping someone can help me out here. My ultimate goal with this code is to extract the color of the sweater I am wearing. Like the title suggests, I'm trying to exctract RBG values from a certain Skeleton point (ie. skeleton.Joint[JointType.Spine].Position).  I do this using the following mapping:

All of the following code is within the SensorAllFramesReady event:

```
private void SensorAllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        if (skeletonFrame != null)
        {
            skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
            skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
        }
    }

    if (skeletons.Length != 0)
    {
        foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
        {
            if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                colorPoint = this.SkeletonPointToColor(skel.Joints[JointType.Spine].Position);                       
            }
        }
    }
}

private Point SkeletonPointToColor(SkeletonPoint skelpoint)
{
    ColorImagePoint colorPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(skelpoint, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
    return new Point(colorPoint.X, colorPoint.Y);
}
```

I assign the returned Point to a variable "ColorPoint", and here is how I (somewhat successful) extract the RBG values:

```
using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
{               
    if (colorFrame != null)
    {
        int arrayLength = colorFrame.PixelDataLength;
        this.colorPixelData = new byte[arrayLength];
        colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixelData);
        blue = (int)colorPixelData[(int)(4* (colorPoint.X + (colorPoint.Y * colorFrame.Width)))+0];
        green = (int)colorPixelData[(int)(4 * (colorPoint.X + (colorPoint.Y * colorFrame.Width))) + 1];
        red = (int)colorPixelData[(int)(4 * (colorPoint.X + (colorPoint.Y * colorFrame.Width))) + 2];
    }
}
```

I then draw an ellipse on my Windows Form window using the retrieved RBG values. Now this works, kind of. I do get a color which resembles the color of the sweater I'm wearing, but even if I do my best to stand very still the color is always changing. It's almost as if I'm getting random RBG values within a certain range, and only the range is dictated by the color of my sweater. Why is this? Is there another way I should be solving this problem?

Thank you for reading!

EDIT: I apologise for the formatting, this is my firs time submitting a question and I realise the formatting in the first code block is a bit off. The SkeletonPointToColor method is naturally not within the SensorAllFramesReady method. My apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I really recomend you have a look at the [Coding4Fun Kinect Toolkit](http://c4fkinect.codeplex.com/) which provides many useful functions for dealing with the Kinect data. There is a for instance an extension for returning a bitmap named ToBitmapSource() which should be of use.

Another observation is that without using some algorithm to get an average of the color values received it's quite normal to have the color values jump around. Also not confident that you can expect the skeleton and image frames to be 100% in sync.

Comment: To my knowledge the frames should be synced when the AllFramesReady event(which is where my code is) is fired. However I appreciate the suggestions in your reply, I'll definitely look into averaging out the values. Thanks!